# Definition of macro to create two parameters from one value

Tags: c++, macros, mfc

I have this definition:

```
using ToolTipMap = std::map<UINT, UINT>;
using ToolTipPair = std::pair<UINT, UINT>;
```

I use it like this:

```
ToolTipMap mapToolTips;
mapToolTips.insert(ToolTipPair(IDC_COMBO_WATCHTOWER_DAY, IDS_COMBO_WATCHTOWER_DAY));
mapToolTips.insert(ToolTipPair(IDC_COMBO_SCHOOL_DAY, IDS_COMBO_SCHOOL_DAY));
mapToolTips.insert(ToolTipPair(IDC_EDIT_DATE_FORMAT, IDS_EDIT_DATE_FORMAT));
mapToolTips.insert(ToolTipPair(IDC_CHECK_USE_CUSTOM_DATE, IDS_CHECK_USE_CUSTOM_DATE));
mapToolTips.insert(ToolTipPair(IDC_CHECK_PLATFORM, IDS_CHECK_PLATFORM));
mapToolTips.insert(ToolTipPair(IDC_CHECK_PLATFORM_MIKE, IDS_CHECK_PLATFORM_MIKE));
mapToolTips.insert(ToolTipPair(IDC_COMBO_NUM_MIKE_USERS, IDS_COMBO_NUM_MIKE_USERS));
mapToolTips.insert(ToolTipPair(IDC_COMBO_NUM_SOUND_USERS, IDS_COMBO_NUM_SOUND_USERS));
mapToolTips.insert(ToolTipPair(IDC_COMBO_NUM_ATTEND, IDS_COMBO_NUM_ATTEND));
mapToolTips.insert(ToolTipPair(IDC_BUTTON_HELP, IDS_BUTTON_HELP));
mapToolTips.insert(ToolTipPair(IDC_COMBO_REPORT_MODE, IDS_COMBO_REPORT_MODE));
mapToolTips.insert(ToolTipPair(IDC_COMBO_WEEKLY_DAY, IDS_COMBO_WEEKLY_DAY));
```

How can I simplify this bit:

```
IDC_COMBO_WATCHTOWER_DAY, IDS_COMBO_WATCHTOWER_DAY
```

So that I just specify:

```
COMBO_WATCHTOWER_DAY
```

And it expand out as the two with a macro?

---

I see that:

- `#` converts a parameter to a text string
- `##` combines two parameters

So:

```
TOOLTIP(a) _T(“IDC_”)#a _T(“IDS_”)#a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::map::emplace` to simplify the code, example

```
ToolTipMap.emplace(1, 2);
```

Or use `ToolTipMap.insert({ 1, 2 });` to avoid the need for `std::pair`

Use `#define foo(x) IDC_##x, IDS_##x` as shortcut for `IDC_x, IDS_x`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

#define IDC_X1 1
#define IDS_X1 1000

#define IDC_X2 2
#define IDS_X2 2000

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> ToolTipMap;

#define foo(x) IDC_##x, IDS_##x
    ToolTipMap.emplace(foo(X1));
    ToolTipMap.emplace(foo(X2));
#undef foo

    for (const auto &e : ToolTipMap)
        std::cout << e.first << ", " << e.second << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

If you don't have many more of these constants I would recommend leaving the code as is. You can just copy/paste the lines without complicated macros. The final code size will be the same, so nothing is gained or lost.